# httparty XML parser not working properly when one item is returned from a REST query

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am trying to use httparty (in a Ruby program) to query a REST service and parse XML code.

I found a weird issue for which if the REST query returns two or more elements, httparty treats those as arrays of HASH.

If the REST query returns one element, httparty treats this as a HASH (and not as an array with one element).

This has the side effect that I cannot upfront cycle with an "each" because when I do that on the variable that contains the hash, it blows up (whereas it works just fine if I cycle against an array of HASH).

This is the piece of code I am using:

```
response = self.class.get("/api/vdc/#{vDC}/peers")

peers = response['References']['Reference']

peers.each do |peer|

# ....various stuff.... 

end
```

"References" is the main tag and "Reference" are the number of items returned, ranging from 1 to many (if 1 the code fails, if many the code works properly).

Thoughts? Thanks!

Massimo.

Comment: It sounds like you can do one of two things: 1) check to see what type of object `peers` is and act accordingly or 2) create a custom httparty parser (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/h/httparty2-0.7.10/HTTParty/Parser.html). #1 is definitely lower level of effort

Comment: Thanks Skram. The workaround I am adoptiong right now is to check whether "peers" is a Hash or an array of Hash(es) and, based on that, respectively not iterating with the Each cycle OR iterating with the Eeach cycle. I was hoping someont could point me to the obvious and that I was doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: the fact of the matter is that that's the easiest way to get around this. You could also look into creating a custom parser by looking at the link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty method to get a consistent behavior is to put the result into an Array and flatten it.

A class sensitive approach:

```
response = self.class.get("/api/vdc/#{vDC}/peers")

peers = response['References']['Reference']
peers = [peers] if peers.is_a?(Hash)
```

A class insensitive approach:

```
response = self.class.get("/api/vdc/#{vDC}/peers")

peers = [response['References']['Reference']].flatten
```

This way, whether a single hash or an array of hashes is returned, the result is treated as an array of hashes every time. You will need to determine if the expense is too high on the flatten method - very large arrays may take some time/memory to flatten out.

Comment: This is awesome Ben. The flatten trick is exactly what I needed. Now I can iterate with an EACH regardless of the numbers of records retruned. It works with both 1 record and 2+ records. Cool! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You bet. Just be careful if the value you are passing in is an array itself... flatten will take all arrays and sub arrays and put all the array values into a single dimension array.

Comment: @BenH `flatten` also take optional argument to define nesting level for flattening, e.g. `flatten(2)` will only flatten to 2 level of nested arrays and not deeper anymore.